# How to render html files in POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

This is my code:

```
    app.post('/convert', function(req,res){
        var auxiliar = "somo Ubuntu command line(this works)";
        exec(auxiliar, function(err, stdout, stderr){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            console.log("Conversion succesful");
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'views/test.html'));
        }
       });
});
```

What I want to do is to change the html file to test.html when the exec **finishes**. But when it finishes it prints well ("Conversion successful") but the html does not change to test.html. How I can solve that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suppose the problem is that you want to render test.html upon successful request. Have you tried using `res.redirect()` and/or `res.render()`? Also with the answer by @Beatle, do you have view engine setup, such as `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that in client side you called /convert using a ajax call.

Calling/Submitting POST request to /convert asynchronously (ajax) will not make the browser render new pages.

Create a form with action attribute as /convert and submit the form.That should render test.html.

**Dynamic Form**

```
$('<form>', { 
    "id": "dynamicForm", 
    "html": '<input type="text" id="input" name="input" value="' + jsonString + '" />', 
 "action":"/convert",
  "method":"post"})
 .appendTo(document.body).submit();
```

**Express**

```
  var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
 extended: true
 }))
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.post('/convert',function(request,response){
    var input=Json.parse(request.body);
})
```

Comment: Yes comes from an ajax call. But the function it's a little bit more complex because I send also some data. How would you create that form?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the complexity? Is it because its a file? Any data that is sent through ajax can be done through a normal form as well.

Comment: Its just a Javascript variable(string) in Json format.

Comment: Please check the answer now.I have added a sample code using jQuery.I know its 2017 and jQuery is dead but this would give you an idea to work upon.Feel free to comment any challenges you encounter.

Comment: Hey Raghu, it works but I had to change post to get of your solution. But now how can I read the json data I send in the form? pd: if I print request.body it prints {}

Comment: Two Things to consider.1)HTTP Get requests cannot have a request body.So you need to handle it as Post Request only.Adding method= Post will help you to achieve that. 2)In express you must use a middleware like body-parser to collect your data into req.body.Updating answer with these changes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried res.render("../views/test.html") or maybe the view directory is incorrect